# How to prevent a console script from closing itself when an error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, auto-py-to-exe

I made an python program that I packaged into `.exe` using `auto-py-to-exe` and if an error throws up the program shows the error and closes itself immediately, so I can't read the error.

And I don't want to make:

```
try:
   #code
except:
   #print something
```

I want it to print out the original python error and just make it not close immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

#### Using the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module

Example using [print_exc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)

```py
import traceback

def hello():
 return 1/0

def my_program():
 try:
   hello()
 except Exception as _: # try to avoid generic exception handlers
   traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 my_program()
```

#### Using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module

Utilizing the logging module can be useful in many cases for example you can enable more verbose logging using some CLI flag or env variable. You can also dump all the logs into a file that can be parsed later.

Simple logging example

```py
import logging

def cfg():
    fmt = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(filename="my_program.log", filemode="w", format=fmt, level=logging.ERROR)


def hello():
    return 22/0

def my_program():
    try:
        hello()
    except Exception as _:
        logging.exception("an internal error happened!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg()
    my_program()
```

Comment: Hi, and where do i put the traceback module the console just closes it self after the error

Comment: A **bad workaround** would be adding an `input()` somewhere to avoid terminating auto-py-to-exe console

Comment: thats what im trying to do but when i put `input()` at the end of the code it doesnt work

Comment: i dont know where to put `input()`

Comment: i dont know where the error will happen so i just want to make console not close it self after error

Comment: ok i figured out the solution i have put the whole code into `try: ` and did `except: traceback.print_exc() input()` and it works